# How to receive full stacktrace with methods, file paths, and line numbers for JavaScript instead native errors via fabric.io in React-native

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

I have manage to setup the fabric.io in ios and android using https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric but the crash report is in native code i.e. java and objective-c, that is completely unhelpful.

Is there way to receive the full stacktrace with methods, file paths, and line numbers for JavaScript instead native errors.

by doing some research I found if I upload **sourcemap** than there is a possibility of receiving the JavaScript stacktrace.

Answer (score 5):

Mike from Fabric here. We do not have official support for React-Native built apps at the moment so if you set things up, you may see less helpful crash logs. We always prioritize being excellent in a few areas rather then ok in many.

Comment: Do you know if Firebase will add support for this in the future now that Crashlytics will become the crash tool for Firebase?

Comment: Nothing to share at the moment @sfratini, but I know many developers would love to see React Native support within Crashlytics. Firebase does support it in some areas: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

Comment: @MikeBonnell now does firebase support crashlatices  react native ?. I have checked that it adds the crash , but not indicating stack trace of the crash

Comment: I do not know, I no longer work on Firebase.

Answer (score 4):

At this moment I am aware of two companies that do this:

1) Sentry: https://sentry.io/welcome/
2) Bugsnag: https://www.bugsnag.com/

I eventually went with Sentry since it has a bigger community and you can install it on premise if you want to.

Bugsnag has a cool feature advertized which is snoozing the crashes which almost made me go for it, but Sentry has it too.

I was using Fabric too, but eventually moved to Sentry due to this.

Comment: The name is `Bugsnag`.